# Custom legend with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let say I have below plot using `ggplot2` package

```
library(ggplot2)

Data = data.frame('Date' = as.Date("2028-01-01") + 1:7,
                    'y' = c(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0),
                    'yLow' = c(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0) - 2.2,
                    'yUp' = c(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0) + 2.2,
                    'Pt1' = c(-1, 1.0, NA, NA, 4.0, 5.0, NA) + 3.2,
                    'Pt2' = c(NA, 1.0, 2, NA, 4.0, 5.0, NA) + 4.2)
Data

ggplot(Data, aes(x = Date, y = y)) +
        geom_line(size = 1, alpha = 0.8) +
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = yLow, ymax = yUp), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) +
        geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = Pt1),  color = "blue", shape = 23)
```

Now I want to make a custom legend in this plot. This legend will only show the information for the area between `yLow` and `yUp` as a rectangle filled with *blue color (with alpha 0.2)*, and information for `y` as *line* and information for `Pt1` as a *point with shape 23*

Here is an example, how I want to have the legend -

[image]

I also want to place the legend in the plot area.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Edited with the answer from @bird

The answer works as long as I have only one variable to be plotted as point i.e. `Pt1`. But if I add another similar variable `Pt2`, I get error :

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Date, y = y)) +
        geom_line(size = 1, alpha = 0.8, aes(linetype = "My line")) +
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = yLow, ymax = yUp, fill = "My area"), alpha = 0.2) +
        geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = Pt1, col = "My point"), shape = 23) +
        scale_color_manual("",values = c("My point"="blue")) +
        scale_fill_manual("",values = c("My area"="blue")) +
        scale_linetype_manual("", values = c("My line"="solid")) +

        geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = Pt2, col = "My point2"), shape = 23) +
        scale_color_manual("",values = c("My point2"="red"))
```

This gives error as

```
Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour',
which will replace the existing scale.
Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 2 needed but only 1 provided.
```

I have few such variables to be plotted as point. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: for example in the ribbon you could add the fill aesthetics in aes with the name you'd like to show in the legend (e.g., `aes(ymin = yLow, ymax = yUp, fill="area")`), then customize it with scale_fill_manual (e.g., `scale_fill_manual("legend title", values= c("area"="blue"))` ). The same coulfd be done for any aesthetics

Comment: ggplot legends are created through `aes`, either via `col`, `fill`, `alpha` or other arguments. Custom legends require deep knowledge of how grobs work and are not recommended. Instead have a column indicate which group (area for example) and line type they are associated with and customize through the various `scale*` functions.

Comment: Okay. Then how can I create some sort of static rectangle with these information manually, so that it will be able to manage right aspect ratio etc. when I save the plot with different height, width information etc? Will that be efficient?

Comment: i recommend to use the `grid` library https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/RProgDA/the-grid-package.html

working on legends with ggplot can be a nightmare in my (still quite limited) experience and converting your ggplot object to a grob gives you a lot of extra control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Date, y = y)) +
        geom_line(size = 1, alpha = 0.8, aes(linetype = "My line")) +
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = yLow, ymax = yUp, fill = "My area"), alpha = 0.2) +
        geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = Pt1, col = "My point"), shape = 23) +
        scale_color_manual("",values = c("My point"="blue")) +
        scale_fill_manual("",values = c("My area"="blue")) +
        scale_linetype_manual("", values = c("My line"="solid"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to move the legend within the chart area at the top-centre position and place horizontally?

Comment: You can do that by adding the following lines to the plot: `theme(legend.box = "horizontal", legend.background = element_rect(fill="transparent"), legend.position = c(0.5,0.98))`. Legend position corresponds to x and y coordinates in the plot (from 0 to 1).

Comment: @bird When I have 2 variables in the data i.e. `Pt1` and `Pt2`, I get error. I have modified my question with this finding. I have few such variables to be plotted as point. Is there any solution?

Comment: @BrianSmith the problem is you cannot have 2 same `geom_color` separately. `scale_color_manual("",values = c("My point"="blue", "My point2"="red"))` should do the trick.